# python - find unused IP / find a number not used in an range of nos?

Tags: python

I have a list of IP addresses (or just numbers for what it matters)

example list:

```
192.168.1.1
192.168.1.2
192.168.1.4
192.168.1.5
192.168.1.7
192.168.1.9
```

what i would like is a function that will show me what IPs/numbers are free in a range.

for example if my range was 192.168.1.1-10, then .3,.6,.8 and .10 would be available, out those available nos i want to return the lowest no.

so far i have my list of IPs and i have used regex and split to get the last octect/number, but dont know what to do next?

```
def getXOctect(ip_address,octect):
    octects = re.split('(.*)\.(.*)\.(.*)\.(.*)', ip_address)
    return octects[octect]

list_of_ips = ['192.168.1.1','192.168.1.2','192.168.1.4','192.168.1.5','192.168.1.7','192.168.1.9']
octect_list = []
for item in list_of_ips:
 octect_list.append(getXOctect(item,4))
#now what?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Youou could try something like

```
usable = [] 
for i in range(1,255): # or whichever are the available ports
    if i not in octect_list: 
        usable.append(i) 
min(usable) # min value of the unused ports
```

Comment: but the number when used in its final form could be up to 254, then -1 would not work would it?

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand it you would want to return 192.168.1.3 in your example? If you know what your numbers are going to look like (like all of the form 192.168.1.x) you could probably just iterate up from 1 and check if your number is free. If it is then return it, otherwise increment and repeat.

Comment: yes, but in my live environment the list of numbers may not be in order (is there a sort function that would work?) also the number could be from 1-254, and i want to find out which is the lowest free no. how would this function look?

Comment: Well if octet_list is a list of just the last number, then you could use octet_list = sorted(octet_list) to sort it